# How to apply an aritmethic operation over each element in the list of lists containing integers?

Tags: matrix, ocaml, tail-recursion

I would like to find out, how to write a function, that would accept two parameters i.e. a' and b' (that are functions), as well as a list of lists;

And then if the sum of elements in any list in the list of int-lists (containing integers I mean) is an odd number, it would perform an operation of multiplication - function a'
(mult. with the same integer -> x * x), over each element in that list.

Otherwise, in case if the sum of elements in any list in the list of int-lists is even, it would perform an operation of addition - function b'
(add. with the same integer -> x + x), over each of the elements in that list.

So, the call of the function with the input would as such be:

```
func a b [[1;3];[8;3]];;
```

... and then the output should look like this:

```
- : int list list = [[2; 6]; [64; 9]]
```

The sum of elements in the first list is even number, so the first list will be additioned
and the sum of elements in the second list is odd number, which means that the second list will be multiplied.

I've written this function in Ocaml as an exercise and I'm really struggling to understand this language; I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong...
Also, strategic help would be much appreciated! - that is, an explanation of how things
actually work here in Ocaml, although I'm not exactly a complete newbie to Ocaml, I'e already learned a lot about tail-recursive functions, it's just the exchange of parameters between functions that's bothering me.

OK, here's the code:

```
let a = List.map (List.fold_left ( + ) 0)
let b = List.map (List.fold_left ( * ) 0)

let rec func a b lists = 
  if lists = [] then 
    []
  else if ((List.map (List.fold_left ( + ) 0)) mod 2 = 0) then 
    List.map (List.fold_left ( + ) 0)
  else 
    List.map (List.fold_left ( * ) 0)

(* Function call: *)
func (fun x -> x*x) (fun x -> x+x) [[1;3];[5;7]];;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with lists of lists here. So you need to `List.map` the list of lists, and also `List.map` each individual list.

When you do `List.map (List.fold_left ( + ) 0)` you have partial application to two function:
For `List.fold_left` you give the function to be applied, and the initial element, and are left with a function that still takes a list.
For `List.map` the first argument (function to be applied) is given, and you end up with a function that would still take the list of lists: So at this point, it is still an unevaluated function. You can't do `mod 2` with it, because you don't have an integer.

Your `a` and `b` defined at the top aren't actually used, because they will be shadowed by the function arguments in your `func`.
When you call `func (fun x -> x*x) (fun x -> x+x) [[1;3];[5;7]];;`, the `a` will be `(fun x -> x*x)`, the `b` will be `(fun x -> x+x)` and your `lists` will be `[[1;3];[5;7]]`.

Your `func` is not a recursive function, it does not call itself. The `List.map` you are using is not tail recursive, and the `List.fold_left` is.
See:
https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALmap
https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALfold_left
This might be useful for understanding tail recursion:   https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2020sp/textbook/data/tail_recursion.html

I'd minimally change your code to this:

```
let func a b lists = 
  let is_even l = List.fold_left ( + ) 0 l mod 2 = 0 in
  List.map (fun l -> if is_even l then List.map b l else List.map a l) lists

(* Function call: *)
let _ = func (fun x -> x*x) (fun x -> x+x) [[1;4];[5;7]]
```

It maps the list of lists, so `l` is a list. Then it checks if the sum of that list is even, and if so, applies the function `b` to each individual element, otherwise `a`.

EDIT:
If you wanted to make it tail-recursive, you can switch out the `List.map` with `List.rev_map`, then reverse the mapped list with `List.rev`.